# inverse of norm of sample random vector

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Given a sample $X＝(x_1,x_2,...,x_N) $ of $N$ i.i.d observation from random variable $x$ of zero mean and positive variance. Intuitively, the expectation 
$\mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{X^T X}]$ tends to 0 as $N$ going to infinity, since the norm of sample vector would become bigger and bigger with high probability. But how to prove it?
Any helps will be appreciate!

Comment: it's you again, haha. But I think $x$ is not necessary to be Gaussion.

Comment: Oops, I missed that.

Comment: can I solve this by following? By the law of large numbers, $\overline{X^T X}\xrightarrow{P}Var(x)$, then by continuous mapping theorem we have $$\frac{1}{X^TX}=\frac{1}{N}\frac{1}{\overline{X^TX}}\xrightarrow{P}0$$.